# PHP Show images from directory that pertains to a selected ID from DB

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm storing vehicle information in a DB and this includes images file names. A user has the option to upload multiple files at once, and those file names are stored in a single row. For e.g, I upload a new vehicle, a Ford, and I have three images for this vehicle. As soon as I hit save, the images are saved in a predefined directory and the file names are stored in the DB. The file names in the DB are split by *.

Here's the code to save the information to the DB:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

//Get form data
$stock_number = $_POST['stock_number'];
$vin_number = $_POST['vin_number'];
$make = $_POST['make'];
$model = $_POST['model'];
$colour = $_POST['colour'];
$milage = $_POST['milage'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$description = $_POST['description'];

extract($_POST);

if (isset($_FILES['images']['name'])) {
    $file_name_all = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['images']['name']); $i++) {
        $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i];

        if ($tmpFilePath != '') {
            $path = 'uploaded_images/';
            $name = $_FILES['images']['name'][$i];
            $size = $_FILES['images']['size'][$i];

            list($txt, $ext) = explode('.', $name);
            $file = time().substr(str_replace(' ', '_', $txt), 0);
            $info = pathinfo($file);
            $filename = $file . '.' . $ext;

            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i], $path.$filename)) {
                $file_name_all .= $filename . '*';
            }
        }

        $filepath = rtrim($file_name_all, '*');
    }

        $sql = "
               INSERT INTO vehicles
               (stock_number, vin_number, make, model, colour, milage, year, price, description, images_path)
               VALUES
               ('$stock_number', '$vin_number', '$make', '$model', '$colour', '$milage', '$year', '$price', '$description', '$filepath')
            ";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


} else {
    $filepath = '';
}

if ($result) {
    header('Location: manage_vehicles.php');
}
```

}

That all works great.

Here's the problem: When I select the information from the DB to display, I need to display the images that pertains to only that record, but it doesn't. It displays all the images, despite displaying the correct information for a selected record. For e.g, if I select the Ford I added earlier, it displays the correct information, but all the images of all the records.

Here's the code for selecting information, the images specifically:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE id='$id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $row['make'];

        $dir = "uploaded_images/";

        $file = $row['images_path'];

        if ($opendir = opendir($dir)) {
           while (($file = readdir($opendir)) !== false) {
               if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
                  echo "<img class='images' src='$dir/$file'>";
              }
          }
       }
  }
}
```

Comment: **Stop now** _Refactor your database correctly_ Use a one to many relationship between your existing `vehicles` table and a new `vehicle-pics` table. [See this simple tutorial](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/relational_database_design.html) or search for one you like. _You will thank me in the long run_

Comment: Why not create a separate table for your image locations that hold an id to be linked to the vehicles table? The way you're storing the data is sorta odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were overwriting the $file variable.
try the below code

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE id='$id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $row['make'];
        $dir = "uploaded_images/";

        $filePath= $row['images_path'];
        $fileArray = explode("*",$filePath); //split the filepath
        foreach($fileArray as $file)
        {
          if(file_exists($dir.$file)) //check if file exist
          {
            echo "<img class='images' src='$dir/$file'>";
          }
        }
     }
  }
```

P.S The code is not tested!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @Silent_Coder. Works perfectly.